# How i can know which imageView i pressed?

Tags: android, imageview

I have three ImageView and two of those have the "alpha" value in 0.4. In this code you can see better:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textlig"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Light" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/nolig"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:alpha="1"
                android:contentDescription="No light"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_myplaces" 
                android:onClick="clickLight"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/freelig"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:alpha="0.4"
                android:contentDescription="Free light"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
                android:onClick="clickLight"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/paylig"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:alpha="0.4"
                android:contentDescription="Light payment"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" 
                android:onClick="clickLight"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

All  have a onClick value which executes clickLight() metod:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void clickLight(View view){

    ImageView nol = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.nolig);
    ImageView frel = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.freelig);
    ImageView pal = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.paylig);

    nol.setAlpha((float) 0.3);
    frel.setAlpha((float) 0.3);
    pal.setAlpha((float) 0.3);


}
```

this code is incomplete, because i need the id of the imageView that i pressed to put the valor 1 in  his alpha.

I was searching in this forum but i didn't find nothing. Someone know something about this or some way for do this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: post your complete code so that it can be edited and you can get solution of the problem

Comment: i haven't added more code because in a few hours there are five good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a ton ways you can code this. Here's a few.

**Option 1 using the `View's ID`:**

```
public void clickLight(View view){

    ImageView nol = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.nolig);
    ImageView frel = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.freelig);
    ImageView pal = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.paylig);
    //You can also use an switch block
    if(view == nol) {
        nol.setAlpha((float) 0.3);
    }else if(view == frel) {
        frel.setAlpha((float) 0.3);
    }else if(view == pal) {
        pal.setAlpha((float) 0.3);
    }

}
```

**Option 2 alternate way of using the `View's ID`:**

```
public void clickLight(View view){

    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.nolig:
            //do something
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.nolig)).setAlpha((float) 0.3);
            break;

        case R.id.freelig:
            //do something
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.freelig)).setAlpha((float) 0.3);
            break;

        case R.id.paylig:
            //do something
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.paylig)).setAlpha((float) 0.3);
            break;

    }
}
```

**Option 3 using a `TAG`:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textlig"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Light" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nolig"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:contentDescription="No light"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_myplaces"
        android:onClick="clickLight"
        android:tag="nolig"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/freelig"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:contentDescription="Free light"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:onClick="clickLight"
        android:tag="nolig"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/paylig"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:contentDescription="Light payment"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:onClick="clickLight"
        android:tag="nolig"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

public void clickLight(View view){

```
switch (view.getTag().toString()){
    case "nolig":
        //do something
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.nolig)).setAlpha((float) 0.3);
        break;

    case "freelig":
        //do something
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.freelig)).setAlpha((float) 0.3);
        break;

    case "paylig":
        //do something
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.paylig)).setAlpha((float) 0.3);
        break;

}
```

}

Honestly though going forward I would suggest using a library like ButterKnife. That's just my personal preference. [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

Comment: Thank you so much! these is the best answer. i used the first option and work very well.

Answer (score 0):

you can ask for the view pressed using the view id.

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
  if(view.getId()==R.id.but_id)
}

remember set the listener to the buttons
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void clickLight(View view){

        ImageView nol = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.nolig);
        ImageView frel = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.freelig);
        ImageView pal = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.paylig);
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.nolig:
                nol.setAlpha((float) 0.3);
                break;
            case R.id.freelig:
                frel.setAlpha((float) 0.3);
                break;
            case R.id.paylig:
                pal.setAlpha((float) 0.3);
                break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
public void clickLight(View view){
    if(view.getId() == R.id.YOURID)  //Replace YOURID with the id of your button.
        view.setAplha(FLOAT_VALUE);  //Replace FLOAT_VALUE with the value that you want to set as aplha.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method receives the clicked `ImageView` as an argument:

```
public void clickLight(View view){
    ImageView clickedImage = (ImageView)findViewById(view.id);
    clickedImage.setAlpha(1.0f);
    // set the other ImageViews
    // ...
```